# TFS Service GitContinuousDeploymentTemplate.12.xaml failing to load parameters

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I'm using Microsoft's TFS Service for source control. I've gone with the git repository option.

I want to continuously deploy builds to an Azure website - so followed the instructions here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/publishing-with-tfs/. In Azure, I choose the TFS Service, Git repository, and follow the wizard.

I get into trouble on "Step 4: Trigger a rebuild and redeploy your project (sub-step 10)". I think this guide is referencing a TFS repository as opposed to Git, so there are some differences...

The build process template has defaulted to
 "GitContinuousDeploymentTemplate.12.xaml". When I edit the build
 definition in Visual Studio Team Explorer, there are a number of
 parameter errors in section 5 of the process section. The errors say
 something to the effect of

> "The parameter xxx [e.g.
>   AutomatedTests|AdvancedTestSettings] could not be loaded because the
>   type InArgument<...> was not found. You cannot edit this parameter,
>   but you can save the build without it".

When I run the build, it seems to fail because of these missing parameters. I can't figure out how to get this working. Does anyone know how to overcome this?

Incidentally, I have changed the settings in 1. Git and 2. Build with settings to point to my web application's .csproj and a release/any cpu build configuration.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using to edit the build? Failure to load parameters is often caused by a mismatch in the versions of assemblies. Your `.12.xaml` template is built to be edited with Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're using an older version than Visual Studio 2013 to edit the build definition. This build definition carries the `.12.xaml` which indicates that you should use Visual Studio 12.0 (2013) to edit the template. I understand it might be confusing that Visual Studio 11.0 = 2012 and that 12.0 = 2013, but that's just how it is.

You can use [Visual Studio Express 2013 or a stand-alone installation of Team Explorer 2013](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs) to create the build definition and edit it. After creation you can trigger the build from an older version of Visual Studio without any issues.

Comment: That sounds very promising, thanks for the response. I can confirm I am using Visual Studio 2012 - I didn't realize the number related to a VS version number. I'll get hold of VS 2013 and confirm.

Comment: Yep, that worked, I needed Visual Studio 2013. Thanks for your help.